# Any Recognize This Short Story About a Demonic Cat?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

What I believe is this is possibly a short story that appeared in Omni Magazine but I can’t be sure & a Google search has yielded no results thus far so I’m asking you good people here for help.

Plot is fairly simple, man receives a cat from ex girlfriend who got cat from devil worshippers who summoned demons to posses the litter of a cat that gave birth.

Man receives one from his former girlfriend who was brokenhearted about how things went between them.  So much so she’s planning to commit suicide soon which the man doesn’t know but on to the story.

The cat whose name I believe is Cinnamon (but again I could be wrong) lives with the man & is quite happy & serves & loves him.   Man meets a woman who is a cheat & double deals him.  She brings home another man to his house while he’s away I guess for his job & cheats on him.  The cat sees all of this go down & exacts revenge on both.

Cat has the power of telekinesis I think & the woman who suspects that there’s more to the cat then meets the eye tries to kill him to no avail.  Cat uses his mind to force her to pick up a blade & turn it against herself, killing her.  Forget what he does to the guy.

Man comes home to find them dead, is upset & at the end the cat tries to nuzzle up to him & comfort him but he’s smacked away due to the man being upset & is kinda taken aback about it.  So at the end he contemplates everything & says “Perhaps indeed there’s no rest for the wicked”.   It’s a very general outline of the story but in a nutshell is this what it is & I believe I’m correct about most of the details.  Hopefully this is enough or you all to go on.  IF I AM correct that this was a story from the now defunct Omni Magazine, maybe those of you familiar enough with it & its short stories may recognize what I wrote & could help me.

Thank you all in advance.  All my best.